# Extract Musical Notes from Audio to array with FFT

Tags: python, django, algorithm, numpy, fft

I'm trying to create a project in which I upload an audio file (not necessarily wav) and use FFT endpoint to return an array with the names of the sounds. Currently, I have such code, but even though I upload a file with only the sound A, it receives the value E-10, and when uploading, for example, title, I receive only one sound. Would anyone be able to help me?

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from pydub import AudioSegment 
import numpy as np
from noteQuiz import settings

#Names of the notes
NOTE_NAMES = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]
 
def freq_to_number(f): return 69 + 12*np.log2(f/440.0) 
def number_to_freq(n): return 440 * 2.0**((n-69)/12.0) 
def note_name(n): return NOTE_NAMES[n % 12] + str(int(n/12 - 1))


def find_top_notes(fft, xf): 
    if np.max(fft.real) < 0.001: 
        return []
    lst = [x for x in enumerate(fft.real)]
    lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    idx = 0
    found = []
    found_note = set()
    while (idx < len(lst)) and (len(found) < 1):
        f = xf[lst[idx][0]]
        n = freq_to_number(f)
        n0 = int(round(n))
        name = note_name(n0)
    
        if name not in found_note:
            found_note.add(name)
            s = [note_name(n0)]
            found.append(s)
        idx += 1
    
    return found

def proccess_audio(request): 
   AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"
if request.method == 'POST':
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['audio_file']
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uploaded_file.name)

    with open(file_path, 'wb') as destination:
        for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

    
        mx = 0
        audio = AudioSegment.from_file(file_path)
        samples = np.array(audio.get_array_of_samples())
        fft_result = np.fft.rfft(samples)
        fft = np.abs(fft_result).real
        mx = max(np.max(fft), mx)
    
        # Oblicz częstotliwości
        xf = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(fft_result))
        fft = np.abs(fft) / mx
    
        s = find_top_notes(fft, xf)
    
        return JsonResponse({'frequencies': s})
    
    return render(request, 'proccess_audio.html')
```

Comment: not a python coder so its hard for me to see what you doing... anyway 1. the processed window of sample for FFT should be centered around actual time (position for music notation) and have size large enough to recognize smallest tone frequencies used. I do not see such thing in your code I would expect the consequent windows would overlap. 2. you need to use power spectrum instead of real part of complex result 3. you have to threshold amplitudes and those that are bigger than threshold recompute to your tone and output it. There might be more frequencies around musical tone frequency.

Comment: so compute power spectrum result: `x.power = sqrt(x.real^2 + x.imaginary^2)` where `x` is single sample output from FFT (you can remove the `sqrt` for speed), set FFT window size based on samplerate of sound and lowest tone frequency wanted to detect, set window speed (samples to move the window per each FFT) either to some small enough constant step or based on tempo (which should be detected ahead)